# an addition list element is added to the browser after i add an unordered list from JS

Tags: javascript, html

```
let leadTracker = ["bbboo","hjkku","hhythjm"];
console.log(leadTracker)
let inputText = document.getElementById("input-text");
let inputButton = document.getElementById("input-button");
let Listing = document.getElementById("listings");
function clicker() {
leadTracker.push(inputText.value);
for(let i = 0; i < leadTracker.length; i++) {
Listing.innerHTML += "<li>" + leadTracker[i] + "</li>";
   }
}
```

just practicing a fw things on javascript but i seem to be having an issue with adding an unordered list to my html from JS. so basically the list is added but an addition li element
is added anytime i try to open it on my browser. I have cosole.logged leadTracker and get that
my array length is 3. Please what can I do?

Comment: Your console logs the array as it's made, however, you added another element to leadTracker using a `push()` (where you added the inputText.value), so now there should be 4 elements in the array. Try logging the array after the push and you'll see that.

Comment: Maybe it's because you console.log leadTracker array before you add a new element? One more case, console.log(inputText.value) maybe it's empty. I want to recommend you use innerHTML only once. In a loop you can save your markup in a variable, and after loop, you can set it to innerHTML once (this approach let you interact with DOM only once, not every loop iteration). 
This way you will get the best performance

Comment: Thanks allot guys. This was helpful. Did not know I will automatic push an empty like tag.